# Why does the first page of one category redirect to empty page 4?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, wp-redirect, redirect

When I load this URL on my WP e-ecommerce site, it 301 redirects to page 4 which does not exist, and appears as a page with empty contents:

Go to this URL: http://comfortboost.co.uk/new/?wpsc_product_category=bath-hoists
And there will be a 301 redirect to: http://comfortboost.co.uk/new/?page_id=4&wpsc_product_category=bath-hoists
Which gives a 404 Not found error.

It should display the first page of the category instead.

Why does this happen? I can provide admin login details if that will help.

This is a fresh installation with barely any changes, but with 4000 products imported in from a wordpress format XML file.

Other categories work just fine and return some content.

Comment: This is indeed weird behavior. There are products in the 'bath hoists' category, I assume? If you have no redirects set in _.htaccess_ and no redirection plugin installed either, this can only be a wordpress redirect. Has there ever been a page with a slug called _bath-hoists_? Search the _wp\_postmeta_ table for a 'bath-hoists' _meta\_value_. The _meta\_key_ (same table) for automatic wordpress redirects is _\_wp\_old\_slug_. My best guess. Too "guessy" to make this an answer, though. Should this be it, I'll create an answer from it later.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I worked around it in the end, see my answer below.

Comment: Madness... Congrats on figuring it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hate the wp-e-commerce plugin.

It turns out that the only products in that category were 'pending', i.e. not published yet. Even if they were moved to trash, and 'hide_emtpy => 1' was used on the categories list, the error still occurred.

Only when the products were completely emptied out of the trash did the category disappear from the menu, and the problem was resolved that way.

The reason it forwarded to page 4 is still unknown.